# How to keep track of user auth state in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to keep track of user auth state in MVVM. In the repository I do this:

```
override fun addListener() = callbackFlow  {
    val listener = AuthStateListener {
        trySend(it.currentUser == null)
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
    awaitClose {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
    }
}
```

Then in ViewModel I have:

```
var state by mutableStateOf(false)
    private set

fun addListener() = viewModelScope.launch {
    repo.addListener().collect { authState ->
        state = authState
    }
}
```

Inside the activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        //...
        viewModel.addListener()
        if (viewModel.signedOut) {
            Log.d(TAG, "currentUser = null")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "currentUser != null")
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm not authenticated and I open the app, the above code fires twice, with two different results:

```
currentUser != null
currentUser = null
```

I tried to add the code inside `LaunchedEffect(Unit) {...}`, it fires only once, but then the screen doesn't recompose anymore.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding a listener, just subscribe to the flow:

In the viewmodel, `@Composable fun getUserAsState() = flow.collectAsState()`
In the UI, `val user by viewModel.getUserAsState()`

Comment: Hey Jorn. Thanks for taking the time to an answer my question. I just tried your solution, but it provides the same result. I got again both log statements.

Comment: If you get both log statements, then the state is changing from having a user to not having one. See why that happens.

Comment: Ok, I'll check that and get back to you. Voted-up.

Comment: I have implemented your solution, but I cannot solve that. So I have added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74716334/why-does-trysend-emit-fake-data). Maybe you can take a look.