# Why does trySend emit fake data?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I need to get user auth state in MVVM. In the repository I do this:

```
override fun getAuthResponse() = callbackFlow  {
    val listener = AuthStateListener {
        Log.d(TAG, "currentUser: " + (currentUser == null)) //Line2
        trySend(it.currentUser == null)
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
    awaitClose {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
    }
}
```

"Line2" will always print `true` because the user is not authenticated. Then in ViewModel I have:

```
fun getAuthResponse() = repo.getAuthResponse()
```

And inside activity:

```
setContent {
    //...
    val response = viewModel.getAuthResponse().collectAsState(initial = false).value
    Log.d(TAG, "response: $response") //Line1
}
```

Since setContent is a composable function, when I open the app, it fires twice. That means that the log statement at "Line1", is triggered twice. When it first fires, I get:

```
response: false
currentUser: true
```

So, the response is printed before, even if I called getAuthResponse() at a previous line. The problem is that for some kind of reason even if the current user is null, I got printed in the activity that the user is not null. When it fires the second time, I got the correct data:

```
response: true
currentUser: true
```

Why do I get a non-null user object? Does trySend emit fake data?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your problem right. You explicitly set `initial = false`, so why are you surprised you initially got `false`? The code inside the listener happens after you printed the response already. So it behaves as I would expect it to behave. Maybe the only unclear part to me is why do you see `currentUser` log twice, I would expect it to be: `response: false; currentUser: true; response: true`, without the last one.

Comment: @broot Then why is second time `true`? Inside the repo, I always get true.

Comment: First `response` log is before the repository even had a chance to emit anything. It just shows what you provided as the `initial` value. Then after the repository emits `true`, response also changes to `true`.

Comment: @broot Fair enough, but if change that, I got the opposite behaviour. If I'm authenticated, true, false, false, false. Somehow, I need to that, or emit only when the value is actually read.

Comment: @broot Can I ignore the initial value somehow?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Android, so I won't help with the architecture, but two possible solutions are: 1. If you can access `currentUser` in the view, then you can do: `initial = currentUser == null`. It may be considered repeating the logic in multiple places. 2. You can use `StateFlow` instead of a regular flow and then I believe `collectAsState()` will get the initial value correctly. But to create `StateFlow` you will still have to wait somewhere else for this initial value, so depending on your architecture it could be acceptable or not.

Comment: Please be aware right now you get the information about the logged user only after `auth` provides you with this info. That means initially we don't know if the user is logged in or not. So either you find a wait to get this info directly or you just can't show this properly straight from the beginning. Maybe initially you need to show a loading screen until you get the proper value?

Comment: @broot But it's not an asynchronous operation. However, I think that `initial = currentUser == null` might solve the problem, but it means that I need to do the same thing in multiple places, which I want to avoid.

Comment: @broot I got the exact same behaviour when I have used StateFlow. Don't know what to do :| I'm really stuck.

Comment: Ok, I looked into Firebase docs and you are correct - we can get the user directly. Ok, so I suggest to not use `callbackFlow()`, but instead create `MutableStateFlow` and set it initially to `auth.currentUser`. In the listener you just change its value. Expose the flow as `StateFlow` type, not as `Flow`. Then in the view you should be able to use `collectAsState()` without passing any initial value - it will use the initial value you used in the first step. I think that should work.

Comment: @broot Let me try that and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: I'm having a hard time implementing that. Can you please add an answer? I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that flows are by design asynchronous. Even if you expect `AuthStateListener` to be invoked immediately after registering it, still the flow initially don't have any value. `collectAsState()` requires a value, it can't be just empty and for this reason it requires you to provide an initial value. You provided `false` and this is what you initially get as the `response`. Then almost immediately listener is invoked, it emits `true` and then `response` changes to `true` as well.

There are multiple ways how we could solve this kind of problems. For example, we could initially show a loading screen until we get the correct value. In the above case we are able to get the value for `currentUser` directly, without using a listener, so I suggest using `StateFlow` instead. `StateFlow` is different than a regular `Flow` as it is able to keep its "current" value. The easiest would be to use `MutableStateFlow`:

```kotlin
override fun getAuthResponse(): StateFlow<Boolean> {
    val flow = MutableStateFlow(auth.currentUser == null)

    val listener = AuthStateListener {
        Log.d(TAG, "currentUser: " + (currentUser == null)) //Line2
        flow.value = it.currentUser == null
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)

    return flow
}

setContent {
    //...
    val response = viewModel.getAuthResponse().collectAsState().value
    Log.d(TAG, "response: $response") //Line1
}
```

This solution may be not 100% correct as I couldn't test it, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I have just added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74717917/how-to-remove-the-listener-when-using-stateflowboolean). If you have time, maybe you can take a look. Thanks again. I was searching for a solution for days.

Comment: Maybe you can also help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74824649/how-to-call-a-function-from-in-viewmodel-in-viewmodelscope).