# How to remove the listener when using StateFlow<Boolean>?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Earlier, I have used this function:

```
override fun getAuthResponse() = callbackFlow  {
    val listener = AuthStateListener {
        trySend(it.currentUser == null)
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
    awaitClose {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
    }
}
```

But due to some constraints that are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74716334/why-does-trysend-emit-fake-data/74717594) I had to use:

```
override fun getAuthResponse(): StateFlow<Boolean> {
    val flow = MutableStateFlow(auth.currentUser == null)
    val listener = AuthStateListener {
        flow.value = it.currentUser == null
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
    return flow
}
```

Which is what I need, but I cannot find awaitClose {...}, so I can remove the listener. How to remove the listener when using StateFlow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your callback flow with `stateIn` to turn it into a StateFlow that only uses a listener when it has collector(s). When it loses all collectors, WhileSubscribed causes the upstream callback flow to terminate, so it will remove the listener. When it gets a new first collector, it restarts the upstream flow from scratch.

To use `stateIn`, you must have a coroutine scope available to run the state flow conversion in. I'm just using GlobalScope for this example. If this is in a ViewModel you might want to use `viewModelScope` instead. Or you could make the coroutine scope an input parameter of the function. I think GlobalScope is probably OK due to the use of `WhileSubscribed()`.

```
override fun getAuthResponse(): StateFlow<Boolean> = callbackFlow  {
    send(it.currentUser == null)
    val listener = AuthStateListener {
        trySend(it.currentUser == null)
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
    awaitClose {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
    }
}.stateIn(GlobalScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), auth.currentUser == null)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to an answer my question. I will try your solution and I'll get back to you. Voted-up.

Comment: I just thought of one potential gotcha with this. The initial value is taken at the time you call `getAuthResponse()`. If you hang onto the reference without attaching a subscriber immediately, or have a break of time with no subscribers, it is possible that the auth state would change while there are no subscribers, but the flow will have the out of date value. So I think you need to do an initial emit of the current value, even though it looks redundant. See edit. Since this is a StateFlow, values are conflated. You won't see two falses emitted in a row downstream.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info.

Comment: I think there is still a small risk of the initial value double-emitting with a wrong value first (your original problem) if the auth state changes in between calling this function and then calling `collectAsState()` on it. Not because of what my code does...I think your code has a similar risk. In that code, if the auth state changes between creating your MutableStateFlow and your listener being registered, it could happen.

Comment: I just passed the viewModelScope as an argument to the getAuthResponse() function and it worked as expected. Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe you can also help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74824649/how-to-call-a-function-from-in-viewmodel-in-viewmodelscope).