# How to call a function from in ViewModel in viewModelScope?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

In the repository class have this listener:

```
override fun getState(viewModelScope: CoroutineScope) = callbackFlow  {
    val listener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
        trySend(auth.currentUser == null)
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)
    awaitClose {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
    }
}.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), auth.currentUser == null)
```

In my ViewModel class I call `getState` function that returns a `StateFlow<Boolean>` using:

```
fun getState() = repo.getState(viewModelScope)
```

And I collect the data:

```
setContent {
    val state = viewModel.getState().collectAsState().value
}
```

If I change in ViewModel:

```
fun getState() = viewModelScope.launch {
    repo.getState(this)
}
```

So it can be called from a viewModelScope, I cannot collect the data anymore, as `.collectAsState()` appears in red. How to solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're trying to do this:

```
fun getState() = viewModelScope.launch {
    repo.getState(this)
}
```

This code launches an unnecessary coroutine (doesn't call any suspending or blocking code) that get's a StateFlow reference and promptly releases the reference, and the function itself returns a Job (the launched coroutine). When you `launch` a coroutine, the coroutine doesn't produce any returned value. It just returns a Job instance that you can use to wait for it to finish or to cancel it early.

Your repository function already creates a StateFlow that runs in the passed scope, and you're already passing it `viewModelScope`, so your StateFlow was already running in the `viewModelScope` in your original code `fun getState() = repo.getState(viewModelScope)`.

Comment: Thank again for answering my question. I'm doing that because when I attach the listener and I perform some operations, I get `kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException`. If I comment `auth.addAuthStateListener(listener)` everything works as expected.

Comment: And calling from a coroutine context will solve the issue. That's the reason for that approach.

Comment: I would have to see what these operations are to understand how this could happen. Not sure what you mean by calling from a coroutine context. A flow is always collected from within a coroutine, so it always has a CoroutineContext.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74823777/how-to-perform-an-async-await-operation-without-exception) are details I was talking about. Maybe you can help me with that.

Comment: Do you need any other information?

Comment: I can't spot where any Jobs are getting cancelled. Maybe it happens under the hood of that `await()` call? I don't have Firebase experience.

Comment: Accepted the answer because you're absolutely right, there is no need for any coroutine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Use live data to send your result of state flow from view model to activity.
In your view model do like this:**

```
 var isActive = MutableLiveData<Boolean>();

    fun getState() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.getState(this).onStart {

        }
            .collect(){
                isActive.value = it;
            }
    }

}
```

**In your activity observer your liveData like this:**

```
 viewModel.isActive.observe(this, Observer {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,it.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            })
```

Hopefully it will help.

Comment: If you just want to convert a flow to live data, your entire code block above could be replaced with `val isActive = repo.getState(viewModelScope).asLiveData()` and it would have the same functionality. But the OP is asking how to create State, not LiveData.

Comment: then @Tenfour04 is correct. We don't need coroutine in view model.